# How to add a ViewController to a ContainerView, This containerView is in a navigationController

Tags: uicollectionview, viewcontroller, uicontainerview

So I have pretty problem here.

I have a navigationController and inside it I have a containerView.

So my problem is, I need to know the best way or the best practice to add a viewController to a container view.

I try to add but in the top of the viewController stays a space equals the space of the navigationController.

Thanks a lot.